# When I do a join, why do I have to specify the actual column name as opposed to the field name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

[One to many documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#example-one-to-many-with-join-table)

Specifically in this bit:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="PART_ID")
public Set<Part> getParts() { return parts; }
```

Do I absolutely have to specify

```
name="PART_ID"
```

i.e. the actual column name in the database as opposed to say

```
name="partId"
```

where `partId` is the `partId` data member in the `Part` class. Doesn't specifying the actual column name `PART_ID` defeat the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a join the `on` clause uses column(s) from both tables, nothing guarantees that the column(s) used are the primary keys for the adjoining table.  Your indicating which column on the source entities mapped table need to be used for the join.  Also nothing guarantees that the field name is different from the column name in the table, since `@Column` can map any field to any column.

If JPA did not allow for the `JoinColumn` to be specified it would be enforcing rules on your database structure. Think of the implications this would have when trying to use JPA on an existing database, which could mean massive code changes if the database did not meet these conditions.  I think it was a very sound choice by the specification writers to allow for the column name to be specified.  Specifying the `JoinColumn` or even `Column` provides an added layer of flexibility to the architecture.

If you want to omit specifying of the joincolumn you can always follow the default JPA naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can join on a column not represented by a field in the target entity, e.g. a parent/child relationship where the Child object does not contain a reference to the Parent object.